# Basis of a subspace with a moving vector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem and I don't know if there is a solution to it.

I try to explain you an example which is simplified with respect to the scenario I have but it gives you a good idea of what my problem is.

You can look at the following figure to help your mind to think about the problem.

---

[image]

---

Imagine we have a set of 2 vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ which span a plane $\pi$. The vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are fixed. Now I ask you:

*I have a vector $v$ which is changing over time, which is already spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ and I want a new basis of the plane $\pi$ which includes the vector $v$ and one between $v_1$ and $v_2$. Because 2 vectors are enough to give us a basis of a plane, how to choose which vector between $v_1$ and $v_2$ to remove?*

Of course we can remove randomly one of them and take the other one. This will work, I mean I will have a basis of $\pi$ formed by $v$ and one between $v_1$ and $v_2$ but this won't work if, over time, $v$ becomes parallel to the one I chose. In this case I should have chosen the other one.

**My conclusion** is that it is not possible to know this thing a priori and it is for this reason that the problem is not straightforward.

What do you think about it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you need to complete $v$ with one of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ to a basis, or are you just looking for any basis of the plane which has $v$ as an element?

Comment: In theory I need to complete $v$ with one of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ but I think that a linear combination between them could also work.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking the vector $v$ and its orthogonal complement $v^\perp$ in the plane $\pi$, i.e., the vector 
$$v^\perp=av_1+bv_2$$ 
which is the solution to the equation 
$$v^\perp \cdot v = 0.$$ This will avoid the problem of a vector "vanishing" when $v$ is parallel to one of $v_1$ or $v_2$

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the reply. 

I had the same idea in the meanwhile, It could work thanks.

Comment: Hi, I thought more about it, and I was wondering how to avoid also a jumping between the vector $v^{\perp}$ and the other perpendicular vector (because, given a vector $v$ of course there are 2 vectors perpendicular to it in a plane).

What do you think about it? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that the vector $v$ changes continuously in time, you can make the perpendicular vector continuous by comparing it at two sequential time-steps. If you have already chosen some $v^\perp(t)$, then you can choose $v^\perp(t+1)$ by solving the above orthogonality equation, then picking the solution whose inner product with $v^\perp(t)$ is positive.